# toggle between checkbox images - but easier

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have two small images of an checked and unchecked checkbox.

My code is working but I think it could be much shorter maybe with .toggle()?
I couldn't figure it out till now, here is the code:

```
$('.uncheck').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('uncheck').addClass('checked');
});
$('.checked').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('uncheck');
});
```

Any jQuery guru here? ;)

Comment: Have a look at toggleClass() - http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: I already found the .toggle Class but I dont understand how to use it with my two classes... I think $('.uncheck').live('click', function(event) is the same and then $(this).toggleClass('checked'); would remove and add the class but how can I remove checked and then add the unchecked class?

Comment: Make sure that your second class overrides your first class, no need to remove on the first click.

Comment: I tried it now for 2 hours and I just dont get it :-( Could someone give me an example please?

Answer (score 2):

If you sure, that element has only one class, You can bind handler on both classes per one binding by separating them with comma. And use toggleClass

```
$('.uncheck,.checked').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('uncheck checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3XhbW/1/

HTML -

```
<div class="checked unchecked">Test Text</div>
```

CSS - (note how unchecked overrides checked)

```
    .checked {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #0000FF;
}
.unchecked {
    color: #000000;
    background: #00FF00;
}
```

jQuery - toggle the unchecked class 'off' first

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('unchecked');
    var myCurrentClasses = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).html(myCurrentClasses);
});
```

I am just posting the class information to the div after the first click so that you can see what class the current div has.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to a checkboxlist?